# How to automatically create default lists at the start of the month in sharepoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint

I need to create a default list for about a 100 associates at the start of the month, so they can enter their utilization time in the list. And create a combined report of the lists to find out the utilized time and un-utlized time.

Comment: Have you considered using folders in your list? One for each month? There would be a lot less clutter and easier reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be achieved by having a Year and Month column in the list. Let me try to detail the steps

- Create a field for Month and Year.
- Set the default values for Month field at the start of every month
- Users can use the same list to fill their time for different months.
- You can create views for different months to pull data

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Hey NRD thanks for the response. I have created a field of month and year. But how do i automatically create lists for all the associates at the start of the month, i.e create 30 lists(each day of the month) for each associate on the 1st day of the month. I really appreciate your help.